# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting for Current Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to formulas in Sheets and have searched for a couple of hours. I'm trying to set conditional formatting on a cell if a text value ('In') shows up within the next three cells on the same row.

| Date | Tom | Jack | Ben |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/13 | Out | In | In |
| 1/20 | In | In | In |
| 1/27 | Out | In | Out |

Something like =COUNTIF(B2:F2, "In")>0 works, but I can't copy the formatting to another row (it uses the same cells referenced in the original formula).

I think =COUNTIF("R[0]C2":"R[0]C4", "In")>0 is closer to what I need, but doesn't seem to work (at least not in Google Sheets).

I don't need to return the value or get a count; I only need the first cell to change color if the value exists in the next three cells, and then be able to copy the conditional formatting to other rows and have it work the same way.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've used variations of =COUNTIF(B2:F2, "In")>0 and =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R[0]C2":"R[0]C6"), "In")>0 without success.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom formula rule if CF.

```
=COUNTIFS($A2:$D2,"In")>=3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your formula worked fine for me - just instead of copying you would use Sheets' autocomplete by dragging the bottom-right corner of the selected cell down (just like in Excel?).

That's assuming you only need this formatting to apply to cells within *the same column*, since you mentioned "copying to other rows", but not columns. If you need relative referencing instead, you can take advantage of relative R1C1 notation with `INDIRECT()`. In your formula, replace `A1` with `INDIRECT("RC[1]:RC[3]",FALSE)` (not `"RC[1]":"RC[3])"`; also, FALSE indicates that you are using R1C1 instead of A1), like this:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("RC[1]:RC[3]",FALSE), "In")>0
```

Then you can copy the cell anywhere and the formatting will apply.